# Create a javascript Cookie for my template

Tags: javascript, cookies

here is my javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function JSalert(){
    swal({   title: "Are Your age 18+!",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: "#009688",
    confirmButtonText: "Yes, Iam 18+ !",
    cancelButtonText: "No, I am not sure!",
    closeOnConfirm: false,
    closeOnCancel: false },
    function(isConfirm){
        if (isConfirm)
    {
        swal("Wellcome !", "Enjoy with us!", "success");
        } 
        else {
            swal("Hurray", "Please Go Back!", "error");
            } });
}
</script>
```

when I reload this page ...Every time its seen:
[image]

Can anyone help me to see it One Time !!

Comment: Please format your text and put it inside a code sample instead of using `<br>` elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a cookie when you show the alert. Then, if the cookie is set, you will know not to show the alert again. If it is not set, you know that you haven't shown the alert yet and should do so now.

You can read about setting cookies in JavaScript [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/cookie).

```
  function doOnce() {
  if (document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)doSomethingOnlyOnce\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1") !== "true") {
    alert("Do something here!");
    document.cookie = "doSomethingOnlyOnce=true; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT";
  }
}

<button onclick="doOnce()">Only do something once</button>
```

Comment: sorry..bro    ..its not working..i think cookie not saved ..can u tell me ...what i do now ?? iam not a good at javascript !!

Comment: can u tell me, How can i set cookie ??

Comment: follow this post  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie

Comment: Upcvoted your answer, and OP should do as well and rtfm